# How to override IsInRole method in MVC 4 Custom Membership?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, isinrole

[image: Table for Custom Membership]

[image: Data for Custom Membership]

I'm very new to MVC. I'm doing a Custom Membership asp.net MVC4. Above are the Table & data i have created. I try to override isinrole method but its not working.Below is the sample code & i don't know where to edit it.

```
       public override bool IsUserInRole(string userName, string roleName)
    {
        User user = repository.GetUser(userName);
        Role role = repository.GetRole(roleName);

        if (!repository.UserExists(user))
            return false;
        if (!repository.RoleExists(role))
            return false;

        return user.Name == role.Name;
    }
```

Now i need to get list of roles for a user from UserInRole Table but the this table is not visible.I have to check whether the User role are matching with `User.IsInRole("Administrator")` .Hope anybody can guide me.Thank u in advance.

Comment: How does having the same name as the role determine whether a user is in a specific role? And why not use the Membership API out of the box?

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because you're comparing the role name with the user name ("a" != "Administrator"). You need something more like this.

```
public override bool IsUserInRole(string userName, string roleName)
{
    User user = repository.GetUser(userName);
    Role role = repository.GetRole(roleName);

    if (!repository.UserExists(user))
        return false;
    if (!repository.RoleExists(role))
        return false;

    return user.Role.ID == role.ID;
}
```

It may differ depending on how your entities are setup though.